# Writing $e^{i\theta}(e^{in\theta}-1)/(e^{i\theta}-1)$ in $(a+i b)$ form

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

How to write:

$$e^{i\theta}\cdot\frac{e^{in\theta}-1}
{e^{i\theta}-1}$$
 in

$$(a+i b)    $$     $$   ?$$

---

I tried to multiplicate by $$e^{i}$$ (the numerator and denominator). And to use $$i^2 = -1$$

But I got nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  We have
$$e^{ni\theta}-1=e^{ni\theta/2}(e^{ni\theta/2}-e^{-ni\theta/2})
  =e^{ni\theta/2}(2i\sin(n\theta/2))\ .$$
Do the same for the denominator, collect exponentials, and you get something of the form $e^{i\alpha}$ times a real number, which should then be easy.

Comment: I got $$e^{i{n \over 2}\theta} {\sin({n+1 \over 2}\theta) \over sin({\theta \over 2})}$$  But I don't know what to do with the sine.

Comment: Since you're looking for the real and imaginary parts, you don't need to do anything with it!  It is just a real number.  You only need to know how to expand the exponential term.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write the denominator as 
$$e^{i\theta}-1 =(\cos(\theta)-1)+i\sin(\theta)$$

and then multiply both numerator and denominator by 
$$(\cos(\theta)-1)-i\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: Or just write it as $e^{-i\theta}-1$, to make it easier.